# Python return type hint of literal string

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

This code is from GitPython library, and in particular from the [cmd.py file](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/3.1.30/git/cmd.py#L1207) (removed comments, to make it more concise):

```
class Git(LazyMixin):
    # A lot of code, removed

    def __call__(self, **kwargs: Any) -> "Git":
        self._git_options = self.transform_kwargs(split_single_char_options=True, **kwargs)
        return self

    # Some more code here
```

My question is what does the return type of "Git" (in quotes), which is a literal string signify. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the enclosing class is Git.

I looked into [python typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), and browsed over all the PEPs mentioned in there, the only similar thing I found is [pep-647](https://peps.python.org/pep-0647/) (similar in that, the type hint is quoted string "TypeGuard[Person]", but does not seem to be related).

Can you help me understand what that means, and preferably a name, or a doc for this?

Comment: See https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references. The name `Git` is not defined yet, so this allows the inner function to return that type in anticipation. Maybe a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148/how-do-i-type-hint-a-method-with-the-type-of-the-enclosing-class though not easy to find if you don't know what this is called.

Comment: This is very cool. Actually the keyword "forward reference" was the key here.

Using this keyword I was able to find few answers (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55320236 which has a good explanation.

Similarly, as you pointed out, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533148). Perhaps you should promote this to an answer, or mark duplicate?

Thanks.